# Template match rotation (semi-palindrome)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

There's resources to detect orientation of images based on objects within the image. However, my search for strategies to detect the orientation of a palindrome image such as a screw is a bit of a dead-end. My problem: given two images - 1 base (image below) and a rotated image at 90 degree clockwise (same image) - detect if it's the same image, but rotated at 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Your question is rather odd, since your image basically has four-fold symmetry that would not distinguish between those rotation angles. There are some other markings, but to know the rotation, you would have to know the initial orientation or have an image at the initial orientation. If I had both images, I would edge detect, then use a polar to cartesian transformation and then do template matching correlation to determine the offset. The offset could then be transformed into the rotation.

Comment: rotation around which fixed point? what's the point of reference?

Comment: @eldesgraciado like a fiducial? no marker. The image above is the base image. When the base image gets rotated at 90 degrees, I need to be able to programmatically confirm that it's the same exact image as the base image.

Comment: @jsibs Can you manually determine if that image is rotated or not? What I'm struggling with here is, as fmw42 pointed out, the base image is symmetrical from that perspective. I mean, it seems VERY difficult to even formulate what constitutes rotation on that base image, let alone build an automated analysis system...

Comment: @eldesgraciado I think I would most likely go down to analyzing the pixel level to determine whether the rotation is a match from the base image? My goal is to confirm that it's the same image, but with a N rotation.